# Using setInterval to restart browser game

Tags: javascript

I'm making a browser game that needs to be able to restart without reloading the page, but I don't want to use Location.reload() because certain things need to be different (I don't want to return the state of the game to exactly what it was when the page first loaded). So, I was thinking of using setInterval again when the game ends (if some condition is true like a key press) to start another game loop.

Say I have some function called main or init which my module returns. Assume that main is the only thing that this module returns.

```
const main = () => {
    func1();
    func2();
    func3();
    loop = setInterval(repeatingFunc, 100);
}
```

somewhere in `repeatingFunc` is the line

`loop = clearInterval(loop);`

This is effectively *game over*. Also in `repeatingFunc`, there's a condition which if true, will execute the line

`loop = setInterval(repeatingFunc, 100);`

The purpose of this second setInterval is to *start again*. Is the way I have it set up bad though? I don't really like that it's repeatingFunc and not main that restarts the game. Is there some way to have main do that work? I'm not super familiar with the browser and how to use multiple setIntervals properly.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a self restarting function, like:

```
var run = false;

function loop(){
 //whatever
 if(run) setTimeout(loop, 100);
}

function start(){
  if( run ) return;
  run = true;
  loop();
}

function stop(){
  run = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works differently from my example? If I put your loop function in main, won't I still need to call loop from somewhere else after game over?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setInterval` you forge the browser to draw. But if you use the `requestAnimationFrame`, the browser will call when he is done with his previous draw.

```js
// Get all requestAnimation from moost browsers
var requestAnimation = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;

// Get all cancelAnimationFrame from moost browsers
var cancelAnimation = window.cancelAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozCancelAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame ||
    window.msCancelAnimationFrame;
window.cancelAnimationFrame = cancelAnimation;

let run = false;

function Update(time) {
    console.log("run time: "+ time);
    // If you do not use the boolean the requestAnimationFrame will be reactevate the animation frame.
    if (run)
        requestAnimationFrame(Update);
}

// Stops the requestAnimationFrame
function Stop() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(Update);
    run = false;
}

// Starts the requestAnimationFrame
function Start() {
    run = true;
    Update(0);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="Start();">Start!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Stop();">Stop!</button>
```